# help for sql query

Tags: sql

i have table with name sample in my database it has threecolumns namely words,D1,D2 and
it has some data like below

```
Words      D1     D2  D3
pleasure    1      0   1
question    0      0   0         
answer      0      1   1
request     1      0   0
scount      1      0   0
```

so now i want to calculate parameter N00 which means scount=0 and also it should check where 0 exists in D1 and D2 so here for "question" D1=0 D2=0 and scount=0 so the result should be 2 because scount=0 and D1=0 , scount=0 and D2=0 this both satisfy so result is 2 i need sql query fro this please help advance thanks.

Comment: Reword your question for clarity. Remove your C# tag. Add a SQL tag. (I'll do these tags for you). Go accept some answers to your existing questions. Return.

Comment: So why have you tagged your question C#, if you only need the SQL? To be honest I still don't understand exactly what this is meant to compute... what would the result be if scount was 1?

Comment: @editors: put quotes in the word "question" and it starts making sense.

Comment: -1 for incoherence: the condition scount=0 makes no sense in the context of the data included, as 'scount' appears to be a data value in the Words column, not a column in its own right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly you want to know how many records there are with scount = 0 and either D1 or D2 = 0, that's a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as N00 FROM mytable WHERE scount = 0 AND (D1 = 0 OR D2 = 0)
```

on second pass I think you're trying to count conditions satisfied, that is, +1 when D1 = 0 and +1 when D2 = 0, but only where scount = 0, that's something like this:

```
SELECT (IF(D1=0,1,0)+IF(D2=0,1,0)) as N00 WHERE scount = 0
```

Comment: thanks for your reply im sorry scount is row not column please check the post i have saved edits

Comment: @vj4u making scount a row makes your conditions too inconsistent for me to parse.  are you computing a value for each row? if so please add a fake column to show what the value should be. if not, please try to clarify how N00 depends on all rows.  Where does D3 come into play?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't add up. You act as if scount is a column but it is a row. And tbh your question is not making sense. Could you perhaps split this up in separate cases like:

```
A: (D1 = 0) AND (D2 = 0)  -> N00 = X 
B: (D1 = 0) AND (D2 = 1)  -> N00 = Y
```

I don't have any idea how to fit in scount in these cases. You cant say the following:

C: (D1 = 0) AND (D2 = 0) AND (scount = 1) -> N00 = Z

This isn't possible because scount is in a different row and has no relation to this row at all.